# Docker cannot find module @nestjs/swagger

Tags: docker, nestjs

I'm building a NestJS application using yarn and I set up the Swagger documentation, which works as intended when running locally with `yarn start:dev` (this script runs the `nest start --watch` command). However, when I try to run the application in docker using the command `docker compose up -d`, I get the error "Cannot find module @nestjs/swagger or its corresponding type declarations" (as seen in the screenshot link below).

[Error output from Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mEey.png)

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /home/ubuntu/viteo-dev/viteo-backend-dev

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn global add @types/node
RUN yarn global add typescript
RUN yarn global add ts-node
RUN yarn global add rxjs
RUN yarn global add reflect-metadata
RUN yarn global add class-validator
RUN yarn global add @nestjs/common
RUN yarn global add @nestjs/core
RUN yarn global add @nestjs/cli
RUN yarn global add @nestjs/mapped-types
RUN yarn global add swagger-ui-dist
RUN yarn global add @nestjs/swagger
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8030
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

This is the docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  viteo-backend-dev:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "8030"
    ports:
      - "8030:8030"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/ubuntu/viteo-dev/viteo-backend-dev
      - /home/ubuntu/viteo-dev/viteo-backend-dev/node_modules
    restart: always
    networks:
    - proxy-manager_proxy-network

networks:
  proxy-manager_proxy-network:
    external: true
```

I've tried re-creating the container using the `docker compose up -d --force-recreate --build` and the `docker compose build --no-cache` commands, but had no luck still.

Comment: If needed I can also provide the package.json file.

Comment: The error you're encountering, "Cannot find module @nestjs/swagger or its corresponding type declarations," suggests that the module @nestjs/swagger is not properly installed or accessible within your Docker container. This issue might be related to how you're setting up your Docker image and the volumes.

Comment: @vlanto am I setting up the image in a wrong way? I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Your Dockerfile looks mostly fine, but there are a couple of concerns: You're using `yarn global add` commands to install NestJS-related packages globally. This is not necessary and might lead to unexpected behavior. Instead, install these packages as project dependencies using `yarn add`. You should have the `@nestjs/swagger` package listed as a dependency in your `package.json` under the `dependencies` section.

Comment: You're replacing the image's `node_modules` directory with an anonymous volume.  Among other problems, this means that changes in your `package.json` file will get ignored, even if you do rebuild the image.  Does deleting the entire `volumes:` block help?  You also seem to have included a link to an image file in place of the error message; can you [edit] the question to include the error in plain text?

Comment: @DavidMaze Deleting the entire `volumes:` block helped! Also, I don't have enough reputation to post images directly, but the error message in the image is the same as the one in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by David Maze, what I needed to do was delete the `volumes:` block of code in the `docker-compose` file, and now the application runs as intended!